# Varaha avatar timeframe

Tags: varaha, parashara, rahu, brihat-parashara-hora-shastra

In BPHS parashara states that, varaha avatar is from rahu. But rahu and ketu were created during the distribution of amrita, and king bali was present. Bali is the grandson of prahlada. But varaha avatar was taken to recover bhu-devi and to slay hiranyaaksha, which happened before rahu ketu creation. Then how did sage parasara attribute varaha to rahu if the timelines are different?

Answer (score 0):

Varaha appeared several times. From bhagavatam source I can tell, Sweta Varaha appeared during Svayambhuva manu manvantara, he didnt killed haranyaksha at this time. Then rakta varaha in red form apperared in cakshusha manvantra that's when he killed Hiranyaksha. Lord Varaha saved earth several times.
You can also refer to Laghu Bhagavatamrita for more details on avatars

Comment: If you are referring to a source śāstra, please cite the ślokas via quoting them or via providing their numbering.